# Difference between implement pieces of UI in var and final variables

Tags: flutter, dart

This [example](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout#lay-out-a-widget) from Google shows how you can store pieces of UI in variables.

```
var stars = Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
    Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.green[500]),
    Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.green[500]),
    Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.green[500]),
    Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.black),
    Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.black),
  ],
);

final ratings = Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [
      stars,
      Text(
        '170 Reviews',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
          letterSpacing: 0.5,
          fontSize: 20,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Note that the `stars` piece of UI is stored in a `var` variable while the `ratings` piece of UI is stored in a `final` variable.

> var stars = Row(...);
>   final ratings = Container(...);

**My questions are:**

- What is the motivation behind this difference?
- When to store a piece of UI in a `var` variable and when in a `final` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name suggest, `var` means something whose value can be changed later on, and `final` is something whose value once assigned will never be changed. So, you can pretty much use any of them, it all depends on your need.

```
var widget = Container(color: Colors.black);
widget = Container(color: Colors.white); // no problem

final widget2 = Container(color: Colors.black);
widget2 = Container(...)// error you can't assign anything to this widget again
```

Comment: I may be wrong but the second example seems like something that goes against Flutter guidelines. Why or when would you like to re-assign a widget?

Comment: It all depends on your use case, I can't think of any as of now.